# Playing Sound with LWJGL and OpenAL

Tags: java, lwjgl, openal

I want to play a background music in my java game. I put all the jars in my project and linked the native files in lib/native/windows.

Also on a clean project a get this error message:

```
Could not locate OpenAL library.    
at org.lwjgl.openal.AL.create(AL.java:151)
        at org.lwjgl.openal.AL.create(AL.java:102)
        at org.lwjgl.openal.AL.create(AL.java:201)
```

Is there any solution so that my programm will work fine?

Comment: Not sure if it would work in this case, but have you tried [rebooting Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20315224/slick2d-unable-to-locate-openal-library)?

Comment: sure. ;) the funny thing is if i put the native libs of lwjgl in Djava library path as absolut path it works, as relativ path (e.g. lib/native/windows) it doesn't - any way to solve this?

Comment: i already found the solution:
adding this to the source code:System.setProperty("java.library.path", "libs");

       //Extracted from Distributing Your LWJGL Application
       System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.librarypath", new File("libs/natives").getAbsolutePath());

Comment: nice work; I just found something similar to that just now... :)

Comment: it takes the relative path and converts it to a absolute path and saves this information to the project properties - just working fine!